# Como identificar a un solo elemento en una lista creada diamicamente. Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

aqui va la primera pregunta de un novato en esto (unas 4 semanas con JS), asi que disculpas si no soy muy claro.

Estoy en importando una lista de restaurantes de una API publica. Y estoy creando una lista dinamica en HTML donde se muestra el nombre, una foto, direcci'on de unos 20 restaurantes. 
Lo que intento ahora ahora, es que al clickar en el nombre (o la foto) de cualquiera de ellos, muestre ese nombre (o la foto) en otra parte del HTML. Lo estoy intentando con un addeventListener , pero sin exito.

No se si con las partes de codigo siguientes sera suficiente o no para ver el problema, si necesitan algo mas, puedo pegar el codigo entero.

```
 function getRestaurans(allData) {

  for (var i = 0; i < allData.length; i++) {

      var spanName = document.createElement("span");
      spanName.setAttribute("class", "name");
      spanName.setAttribute("id", "orpName");
      var restaurantName = allData[i].restaurant.name
      spanName.innerHTML = restaurantName
      var orpName = document.getElementById("orpName")
      orpName.addEventListener('click', changeName);

  }

  function changeName(restaurantName) {
    var oneName = document.getElementById("oneName");
    console.log(restaurantName)

      oneName.innerHTML = restaurantName
  }
```

Y la parte de HTML

```
<div>
            <img id="oneRestaurant" alt="restaurant image" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ZawU-NBG6OY/maxresdefault.jpg">
            <p id="oneName"class="spDescription">Restaurant Name</p>
            <p class="spDescription">Address</p>

        </div>
```

Esta es mi solución :

```
var nameContainer = document.createElement("div");
  nameContainer.setAttribute("class", "nameContainer");
  nameContainer.setAttribute("id", "nameDiv" + i);
  var spanName = document.createElement("span");
  spanName.setAttribute("class", "name");
  spanName.setAttribute("id", allData[i].restaurant.id);
  var restaurantName = allData[i].restaurant.name
  spanName.innerHTML = restaurantName

  nameContainer.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // console.log(i)
    var targetElement = document.getElementById('oneName');
    console.log(targetElement)
    changeName(targetElement, event);

  })

function changeName(target, event) {
console.log(event)


  target.innerHTML = event.target.textContent
```

Comment: Entiendo que ya consigues listar tanto los restaurantes que has creado como insertarlos en el DOM, correcto?

Comment: Si, asi es, la lista la importo, y muestra una imagen, el nombre y direccion. 
Si crees que ayuda mas, puedo pegar todo el codigo.

Comment: Estas repitiendo **id**. El **id** debe ser único en el documento. Añade al id un contador (el del bucle te sirve).

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev algo como id="#orpName" ??

Comment: No, algo como `spanName.setAttribute("id", "orpName" + i);`. Y luego `var orpName = document.getElementById("orpName" + i)`, donde `i` es el contador del bucle.

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev ok, lo pillo. Voy a probar. Gracias!

Comment: a la hora de encontrar ese elemento por ID, deberia ser tambien :
var orpName = document.getElementById("orpName" + i) ?

Comment: Lo que dice @EvgeniEnchev es cierto, pero realmente para solucionar esto le da un poco igual, a fin de cuentas el eventListener lo puede enganchar al elemento directamente y no llamarlo a través de un selector. O sea, orpName y spanName, acabarán siendo lo mismo en su ejemplo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que te sucede, entre otras cosas es que cuando añades el eventListener le estás pasando la información del evento, no propiamente el valor que le quieres añadir.

Te sugiero que añadas el eventListener al elemento en sí, y no al ID.

Te dejo un pequeño ejemplo, a ver si te sirve.

```js
const myListOfElements = [
 {
  id: 1,
  name: "Elemento 1",
  img: "https://placehold.it/300?text=Elemento%201"
 },
 {
  id: 2,
  name: "Elemento 2",
  img: "https://placehold.it/300?text=Elemento%202"
 },
 {
  id: 3,
  name: "Elemento 3",
  img: "https://placehold.it/300?text=Elemento%203"
 }
];

const createElements = (elementsArray) => {
  const container = document.querySelector('#container');
  
  elementsArray.forEach(({id, name, img}) => {
     const element = document.createElement('div');
     
     // creamos el span y lo añadimos al elemento padre
     const elementSpan = document.createElement('span');
     elementSpan.innerText = name;
     element.appendChild(elementSpan);
     
     // creamos la imagen y la añadimos al elemento padre
     const elementImg = document.createElement('img');
     elementImg.setAttribute('src', img);
     elementImg.setAttribute('alt', name);
     element.appendChild(elementImg);
     
     // añadimos el eventListenet
     element.addEventListener('click', () => {
       const targetElement = document.querySelector('#oneText');
       targetElement.innerText = name;
     });
     
     // añadimos el elemento al nodo contenedor
     container.appendChild(element);
  }) 
}

createElements(myListOfElements);
```

```html
<span id="oneText">ESTE TEXTO DEBE CAMBIAR</span>
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Comment: wow...eso es mucho mas de lo que esperaba como respuesta. Voy a estudiarlo a ver si puedo implementarlo. Muchísimas gracias, de verdad!

Comment: Sin problema, cualquier duda, me dices

Comment: La primera dudilla ...cual es la funcion del # en "#container" y "#oneText"

las arrow functions aun casi no las conozco (lo mio por ahora son los for loops ), pero creo que puedo apanharme.

Comment: El querySelector identifica un tipo de elemento, # indica que es un id, y un punto (.) indica que es una clase. O sea, document.querySelector('#a') es lo mismo que document.getElementById('a')

Comment: ah, claro , como los selectors en CSS ...tonto de no darme cuenta.

Comment: otra preguntilla teórica (si estoy abusando, me dices, no hay problema) :
el const container = document.querySelector('#container')  
, lo usas solamente para poder añadir despues el elemento al nodo contenedor en
container.appendChild(element) ??

Comment: WOOOOW....it worked!!!!! 
basicamente tan solo cambie en mi ejemplo el getElementById del addevent listner por el querySelector, tal como decias,  (bueno, y use la arrow function tal y como la escribiste) y Funciona!!!! aun no acabo de entender porque, pero me pondr'e a ello. 
Muchisimas gracias!!!

Comment: retiro lo anterior ....funciona...pero solo añade el nombre del último de la lista.  ..me emocioné demasiado rapido :D

Comment: Lo que preguntas del container, si, solo lo uso para eso ;)

Comment: Si quieres, pasó esto a un chat y vemos tu caso concreto con calma ;)

Comment: Lo que si me gustaria preguntarte ...porque estoy seguro de que tendre dudas similares en partes posteriores de este proyecto, si podria hacerte alguna consulta en privado...

Comment: Si tienes más dudas, siempre puedes poner más preguntas aquí, para contactar conmigo en privado, en mi perfil tienes la info ;)

Comment: Sin duda lo hare ...aunque encuentro a veces complicado saber como debo formular la pregunta para que pueda ser respondida, sin tener que pegar todo el codigo completo, que entiendo puede ser demasiado, y que aun asi parezca comprensible .... 

Muchas gracias de nuevo!